# Mysql Partition Doesn't Work Correctly

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, mysql-5.5

I have a partition table which is partitioned by Date, here's my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `BBDD` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MSISDN` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CIF_NIF` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PLANDEPRECIOS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  .
  ..
  ...
  `Operador` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`fecha_carga`),
  KEY `MSISDN` (`MSISDN`),
  KEY `MSISDN_2` (`MSISDN`),
  KEY `BBDD` (`BBDD`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1607074 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( to_days(fecha_carga))
(PARTITION p20120701 VALUES LESS THAN (735050) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20120801 VALUES LESS THAN (735081) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  .
  ..
  ...
 PARTITION p20181001 VALUES LESS THAN (737333) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20181101 VALUES LESS THAN (737364) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20181201 VALUES LESS THAN (737394) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION pdefault VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

The amount of rows is about 1330122, so now it's time to test my partition and the amount of rows my partition scans, here we go:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS    SELECT  *
    FROM  adsl.BBDD
    WHERE  fecha_carga >=
              cast(date_format(DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -1 month),
                              '%Y-%m-01') as date )
      and  (MSISDN=622605810
              or  CIF_NIF=622605810
           ) ; 


The analizer returns:
id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: BBDD_adsl
   partitions: p20120701,p20151001,p20151101,p20151201,p20160101,p20160201,p20160301,p20160401,p20160501,p20160601,p20160701,p20160801,p20160901,p20161001,p20161101,p20161201,p20170101,p20170201,p20170301,p20170401,p20170501,p20170601,p20170701,p20170801,p20170901,p20171001,p20171101,p20171201,p20180101,p20180201,p20180301,p20180401,p20180501,p20180601,p20180701,p20180801,p20180901,p20181001,p20181101,p20181201,pdefault
         type: ALL
possible_keys: MSISDN,MSISDN_2
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1351342
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

As you can see, it scans the correct partitions but the amount of rows is too high (1351342) and it's like if I were making a full scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only useful index is `INDEX(fecha_carga)`, which you don't have.  So, the best it can do is scan a year's worth of partitions.  There are many points to be made here, bear with me...

- `OR` makes it essentially impossible to optimize `MSISDN=622605810 or CIF_NIF=622605810`.  A `UNION` (see below) would help, perhaps significantly.
- For date-related `RANGE` partition, the "first" partition is scanned regardless of the value coming in.  This is a quirk to allow for `NULL` or invalid `DATEs` coming in.  (Yeah, it should be smart enough to see that your dates are valid, but it is not.)  Your best defense is to have a dummy partition at the beginning -- it should be 'old enough' to have no data.  This will at least make the scan of it go faster.
- Do not have partitions for the "future".  Instead, create a new one when needed.  I like to have a single partition named `future`.  Then, just before the clock ticks, I `REORGANIZE PARTITION future INTO ...` to create next month's partition *and* a new `future`.  Because `future` is empty, this action is essentially instantaneous.  More details in [my partition blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).
- `CIF_NIF varchar(255)` and `CIF_NIF=622605810` don't work well together.  The execution has to parse each value and convert it to a number for comparing.  This makes any index impossible to use.  Either change the field to `INT UNSIGNED` (or some numeric datatype) or put quotes around the number (so that it is a string comparison).

Here's the `OR` --> `UNION` (with some simplifications):

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  adsl.BBDD
    WHERE  fecha_carga >= ...
      and  MSISDN=622605810
UNION  DISTINCT  -- or  ALL 
SELECT  *
    FROM  adsl.BBDD
    WHERE  fecha_carga >= ...
      and  CIF_NIF='622605810'
```

Also, replace the two indexes on `MSISDN` with these composite indexes:

```
INDEX(CIF_NIF, fecha_carga), INDEX(MSISDN, fecha_carga)
```

With these changes (reformulation of `SELECT`, plus better indexes), it will be much faster with or without `PARTITIONing`.  In fact, `PARTITIONing` will provide zero performance improvement.

If you are "purging" old data via `DROP PARTITION`, that is a very good reason to keep the `PARTITIONing`.  (Again, see my blog.)

Comment: Rick, i apreciate your answer. By the way all I have read about Innodb point out about no making index of a primary key, as you can see, i have a composite primary which is needed for my partition table (it needs to be partition because it will continue growing). So your answer is really interesting but your composite index are against innodb index convention. Do you have another suggestion please? or am i wrong on something?
One more thing, as my first parameter is fecha_carga, my first index should be something like (fecha_carga, msisdn)? ...just asking.

Comment: Rick, One more thing. whats the matter making a new index on fecha_carga, is not work of partition to go to the right partition and scan by msisdn or cif_nif?. This isn't clear to me, so please clear this to me, I accept that I should have an index on fecha_carga but on a partition table, I shouldnt.

Comment: With the original partitioning and indexes, it went to the correct partitions (plus a few others), then scanned the entire partition.  It could not do less than scan the partition because of the `OR`.  My suggestion involves multiple changes -- OR->union, add indexes, etc.  No single change is sufficient.

Comment: Rick, but it doesn't make any sense. I have made a test on my localhost with 1500000 rows and i didnt add any index and make a query by date and it goes to the right partition with the amount of rows that belongs to that partition, i didn't need to add an additional index to have exactly the rows my partition has. As you can see on my question above, it goes to the right partition but it returns more than 1 millions rows, and that's unlogical because each partition should have as a maximum arround 40000 rows not more than a million rows.

Comment: Do not trust `EXPLAIN's` Row count -- it is an estimate, not the exact number.  It can be too high or too low, and even _very_ far off.

Comment: With some changes, the query will run 10, maybe 100 times as fast, and have much smaller "row" counts.  (The `EXPLAIN` counts still won't be correct; that cannot be fixed.)

Comment: Your point is that I am answering the wrong question.  OK, I jumped to the conclusion that you wanted to speed up the query.

Comment: "and it's like if I were making a full scan" -- it _is_ making a _full_ scan of the partitions that it is touching; that is correct.

Comment: Amazing it works really as your advice said. It would be good for the analizer to return correct information about rows scanned. something that isnt still on my mind is why should i place an index on fecha_carga, its suppose to enter directly because i start my selectivity with where fecha_carga>'somdate' :), if you could gimme more detailed information, I'll be thankful.

Comment: (I removed my date expression, since it did not provide the same value as yours.)

Comment: With the partitioning, `INDEX(fecha_carga)` is not necessary.  (My mistake.)  This assumes you always say `WHERE fecha_carga > start-of-some-month`.

Comment: With partitioning _and_ always start-of-month, `INDEX(CIF_NIF)` is just as good as `INDEX(CIF_NIF, fecha_carga)`.  Without partitioning _or_ other with other time ranges, `INDEX(CIF_NIF, fecha_carga)` is important.  (In both cases, `UNION` is important.)

Comment: Did my last 3 comments satisfy your questions of 2 hours ago?  If not, rephrase the question.

Comment: Yes Rick I'm convinced you are right about almost everything, there are some things i didn't know but now that you have clear my doubts I'm quite. By the way the query using union all makes it faster. I'm happy. I have one more question here that none can answer and is about why when you make a left join with another table you will always have to make a group by?

Comment: A `JOIN` (`LEFT` or not) often creates a result set bigger than the first table.  (Or the second.)  If you were hoping to end up with one row in the resultset for one row in that table, you need the `GROUP BY` to reel in the resultset.  Experiment -- Try a query (preferably on small tables) both with and without the `GROUP BY`.  Display the entire resultset.  (There are many variants of this question and answer -- your test _may_ fail to show my point.)